# When writing a maven plugin, how can I get the Artifacts based on a modified pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, aether, versions-maven-plugin

I am working on enhancing the versions-maven-plugin.  I want to tentatively modify the pom.xml files for a project, then look at the version conflicts of the modified pom.xml to decide what modifications should be kept.  I have found MavenXpp3Reader.read(String) that returns a Model but it is very raw.  I not only need the version properties to be resolved, but I also need transitive dependencies, or even better, the version conflicts.  Can anyone provide some help?  I remember hearing about aether and found out that it was renamed to maven-resolver-provider, but I'm not sure that I should be using that in a plugin, or even if I should, I don't know how to use it.  Can anyone help?

FWIW, the exact issue I'm working on is https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/270

Comment: In the versions-maven-plugin there is a complete handling to update a single dependency and correctly write back a modified pom.xml to file system...furthermore Eclipse Aether was not renamed it was migrated to Apache Software Foundation into Apache Maven project under the name ["Maven Resolver"](http://maven.apache.org/resolver/) (internal package structure is being kept)...I would start with the output of versions-maven-plugin (display-dependency-updates) which can be used to update step by step each dependency....

Comment: I have already worked on script based solution...I would be interested to further work on such things...Apart from that currently we are developing a [shared component](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/) to handle things like this ..get all versions of a particular dependency etc...I would suggest that you contact me via email....

Comment: I am really hoping to implement this as a maven plugin.  I am very interested in getting this feature done, and ideally added to the versions-maven-plugin.  I'm happy to contribute to whatever helps that happen.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I don't see a way to email you.

Comment: Go via github.com/khmarbaise should be possible to send a message...